# Linux expect. How to remove first blank line with "log_user 0"?

Tags: linux, expect

I have this script.

"log_user 0" will hide ask password, but leaves a blank line. **I would like to remove this empty line.**

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0
set timeout 10

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  send_user "Usage: sshpwd \'password\' ssh ...\n"
  exit 1
}

set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set pwd [lindex $argv 0]

eval spawn $cmd
expect {
    "*yes/no*" { send "yes\r" ; exp_continue }
    "*assword:" { send "$pwd\r"; interact; }
}
```

Example of execute (**empty line** before 123):

```
username@localhost:~$ ./sshpwd.exp password ssh username@localhost "(echo \"123\") && date '+%Y.%m.%d' && echo [TEST]"

123
2016.04.06
[TEST]
```

Example of execute if I delete string "log_user 0" in the script (no blank line before 123, but have 'spawn...', 'passw...'):

```
username@localhost:~$ ./sshpwd.exp password ssh username@localhost "(echo \"123\") && date '+%Y.%m.%d' && echo [TEST]"
spawn ssh username@localhost (echo "123") && date '+%Y.%m.%d' && echo [TEST]
username@locahost's password:
123
2016.04.06
[TEST]
```

I would like to see this output:

```
username@localhost:~$ ./sshpwd.exp password ssh username@localhost "(echo \"123\") && date '+%Y.%m.%d' && echo [TEST]"
123
2016.04.06
[TEST]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `spawn -noecho ...`

Also, instead of `eval spawn -noecho $cmd`, it's safer to do this:

```
spawn -noecho {*}$cmd
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I wrapped in a script with sed '1 d' in out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say you wrapped the script with sed '1 d'.  Can this be done in the same script file wrapping the full expect command?